# Could the Low Quality review queue detect previous actions on a post?

Tags: bug, flags, reviewing

I almost always have Arqade open on a tab watching for new questions to pop up while doing other things. When they do, I look at them, and sometimes I will flag them if needed.

The problem is that if I flag something on the site normally, sometimes while going through the Low Quality review queue I will find a question that I have already flagged, and I cannot use the recommend close button and navigate through to the next post in the queue.

Now obviously I shouldn't be able to flag it *again*, but my only choices left are "looks okay" which it doesn't, "edit" which it may not need, or "skip" which I shouldn't have to push, as I've already reviewed it.

So can the recommend close button be made to navigate you to the next post in the queue as it can already detect you have raised a flag on the post? It would basically be like the first post queue which has the "I'm Done" button appear if it detects you have already raised a flag on the post.

Comment: What's wrong with hitting skip in this senario?

Comment: @Dallium I could hit skip, but it seems like I should be able to say I'm done as I have reviewed it, and since I have reviewed it, shouldn't I be able to get credit for reviewing it?

Comment: @Dragonrage It's a single review point, don't get hung up about it.